# Double series with Beta reciprocals $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}\frac{y^k}{k!} \frac{1}{\boldsymbol{B}(j+1,k+1)} = ? $

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, beta-function, laguerre-polynomials

In my research I encountered the following double series involving reciprocals of Beta functions:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) :=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}\frac{y^k}{k!} \frac{1}{\boldsymbol{B}(j+1,k+1)} = \ ? 
\end{equation}
where $x,y$ are non-negative and
$\boldsymbol{B}(j+1,k+1) := \frac{j!k!}{(j+k+1)!}. $

Is there a known closed form for $f(x,y)$?

Some ideas:
1.The summation over $k$ yields
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} (j+1) L_{-(j+2)}(y) = e^y\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} (j+1) L_{j+1}(-y),
\end{equation}
where $L_{n}(x)$ is the $n$-th Laguerre polynomial. In the same way, summing first over $j$ yields
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = e^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!} (k+1) L_{k+1}(-x).
\end{equation}

2. Alternatively, using the integral representation of the Gamma function it follows that
   \begin{equation}
   f(x,y) = \int_0^\infty I_0(2\sqrt{xt}) I_0(2\sqrt{yt}) t e^{-t} dt,
   \end{equation}
   where $I_0(x)$ is the zero-order modified Bessel function of the first kind.
3. Thanks @Tyma Gaidash for pointing me towards hypergeometric functions in two variables. The series is a special case of a [Humbert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series):
   \begin{equation}
   f(x,y) = \Psi_2(2,1,1;x,y)
   \end{equation}

I am happy about ideas and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: There definitely is a “closed form” in terms of hypergeometric functions. Not sure if these evaluate to anything more explicit for any $x,y$…

Comment: Note: Mathematica finds $f(x,x)=\mathrm e^{2 x} ((2 x+1) I_0(2 x)+2 x I_1(2 x))$ where $I_0,I_1$ are [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions).

Comment: Right I was already checking some properties of hypergeometric functions as
$L_{-(k+2)}(x) = 1F1(2 + k, 1, x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Appels series do not seem to work here (directly), due to the falling factorials in the expressions. By the way, it is fine to assume that |x|<1, |y|<1.

Comment: You are right. Indeed the coefficients in the Appel series are rising factorials. I got confused since the notation on wiki is different.

Comment: I derived the same integral representation earlier but with $t\operatorname e^{-t}$ instead of $\mathrm e^{-t}$. Are there particular values of $x$ and $y$ for which you seek a more explicit expression of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash The Humbert series might help, there are some transformations in the literature. I will check for something useful. Thanks!

Comment: @nejimban Thanks, the $t$ was missing. Indeed, the actual variables are $x=a z/(1+z) $ and $y=b /(1+z)$, where $a,b,z$ are positive real numbers and we can assume $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$. Let me know if you are interested in the context.

Comment: There is a simpler closed form for $x=-y$ too, but literature gives not much else.

Comment: Yes, I saw quite some closed forms for $x=-y$ [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10652469.2017.1297438?), but nothing useful for the general case with coefficients (2,1,1).